# How to connect in php to mysql on another Ubuntu-computer

Tags: php, mysql, sockets, ubuntu, phpmyadmin

Here is the setup: Windows (client) + Ubunto 20.04 (server) on different computers on LAN.
I have made permission to access phpMyAdmin from LAN-addresses on apache server.
From the client I can write http://192.168.0.60/phpmyadmin and connect to the database on the server. That works. In phpMyAdmin on client is says "Server: Localhost via UNIX socket".

I want to **connect from PHP script** to the same database - just like phpMyAdmin did - using mysql_connect/mysqli (or other whatever is possible).

However I cannot figure out how to do that, but it is obviously possible as phpMyAdmin does it.

I have tried several things now (attempts include):

```
$socket = '/opt/lampp/var/mysql/mysql.sock';
new mysqli('localhost','user','pwd', "database ",3306,"192.168.0.60".$socket);
new mysqli('localhost','user','pwd', "database ",3306,$socket);
new mysqli('192.168.0.60','user','pwd', "database ",3306,$socket);
```

and several others. File to $socket is correct on the server. But phpMyAdmin does not even ask for such info, it just connects. Help is needed.

How do I connect?

Comment: If starting out use PDO, not MySQLi. See https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php if that fails please provide error message.

Comment: `phpMyAdmin does not even ask for such info, it just connects`... because it's all specified in a configuration file behind the scenes. You need to tell PHP how to connect. You rarely need to specify the socket, though. Usually you can just give the IP address and port number. Make sure you've configured mysql to accept remote connections and ensure there isn't a firewall rule on either computer interfering. You didn't say what error you're getting, btw

Comment: Also, remember that phpMyAdmin is accessing the database locally and you are accessing phpmyadmin remotely via a portal managed by apache/nginx or something. So if there is a firewall between you and the database (e.g. iptables) that will block a direct database connection. Similarly, mysql users can be configured to only allow login from specific addresses so that could also be an issue. Without some kind of error message we can't really point you in the right direction.

Comment: Ok. So I tried PDO
`$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=192.168.0.60;dbname='.$db, $user, $pwd);`
Getting this msg: **Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002]** (translated) Host is not responding.

Comment: And `$dbh = new PDO('mysql: unix_socket='.$socket.';host=192.168.0.60;dbname='.$db, $user, $pwd);` yields same error. I am not reaching the remote coputer.

Comment: Ok so did you do any of the steps and checks which have already been mentioned to you?

Comment: @ADyson I have added a user from "%" and granted all priviliges.  I have tried again with both PDO's and I have tried adding `port=3306` to the connection string. I get the same errors. Can a firewall be blocking if phpMyAdmin is getting through? BTW the client setup is an fresh install of XAMPP 8.0. On the server I have given access to LAN IPs only to access phpmyadmin, insted of `require local`. It is LAMPP with php 7.4

Comment: phpMyAdmin is connecting from the same machine the database is on, whereas you're trying to connect from a different machine, so yes the difference could easily be a firewall, on either machine (or both)

Comment: @ADyson I get it now. I had obviously not grasped that point. I tried to disable firewall on server and the most simple form `$conn = new PDO('mysql:host=192.168.0.60;dbname='.$db, $user, $pwd);` then worked like a hot knife through butter. This will save me days of work. Thank you, thank you, thank you. Merry Christmas!